# Will removing the catalytic converter on my Kawasaki Bajaj RS200 require remapping?

Tags: motorcycle, fuel-injection, kawasaki, bajaj

I own a 2018 Kawasaki Bajaj Rouser RS200 and would like to remove the catalytic converter but am not sure if that would require remapping. I already replaced the stock muffler with one from Vmax Racing and the air filter is stock. I am also considering changing out the stock air filter for a K&N model if it is possible to remove the catalytic converter without major modifications.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1):

Pulling the cat, in and of itself, will probably won't need a remap. Your problem is, when you start adding all the little things together (ie: cat, muffler, intake, etc), you surely could need one. The more things you change, the more likely you're going to need one. The ECU can keep up with a little bit of change, but soon will run out of "room" to adjust. You may already be out of adjustment room for what the ECU can deal with. The only way you're going to be able to tell is if you take it somewhere you can get it read and see where the bike is running. That's the only way you can tell where you're at and whether you're going to need a retune or not.

Comment: Thanks … the catalytic converter removal and change of air filter is as far as I will ever go .